# display:flex - unwanted spacing on iOS devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox

http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/

This is happening across the entire site. on iOS devices, it looks as if there is letter spacing between each letter, when there is none. Everything displays correctly across all other browsers, but isn't working correctly in Safari OR chrome on iOS devices.

Each letter is separated so that it can be animated (using [anime.js](http://animejs.com/)).

I went through and made sure that all vendor prefixs have been added as well to help, and it did not.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I resolve the spacing issue around each letter?

How it looks on iOS devices:
[image: how it looks on ios devices using safari AND chrome]

```js
  var opac = anime({
    targets: '.letter',
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    easing: 'easeInBounce',
    delay: function (el, index) {
      return index * 50;
    },
    direction: 'normal',
    loop: false,
    duration: function (el, i, l) {
      return 80 + (i, l * 50);
    },
  });

  var locations = anime({
    targets: '.locations',
    direction: 'normal',
    opacity: 1,
    loop: false,
    delay: function (el, l) {
      return 450 + (el, l * 500);
    },
    duration: function (el, l) {
      return 80 + (el, l * 150);
    },
  });
  var locationsbuttons = anime({
    targets: '.locations, .buttons,  .locations span',
    translateY: 30,
    direction: 'normal',
    opacity: 1,
    loop: false,
    delay: function (el, l) {
      return 3850 + (el, l * 300);
    },
    elasticity: function (el, i, l) {
      return 200 + (i, l * 500);
    },
  });
```

```css
.name .word {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.name.big {
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 0 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.name .letter {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
      transform: scale(0.9);
  line-height: 1em;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.fat {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
    <link href="http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/1.0.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="name big">
  <div class="word">
    <div class="fat">
      <div class="letter">M</div>
      <div class="letter">e</div>
      <div class="letter">m</div>
      <div class="letter">o</div>
      <div class="letter">r</div>
      <div class="letter">i</div>
      <div class="letter">e</div>
      <div class="letter">s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">m</div>
    <div class="letter">a</div>
    <div class="letter">y</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">f</div>
    <div class="letter">a</div>
    <div class="letter">d</div>
    <div class="letter">e</div>
    <div class="letter">,</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">b</div>
    <div class="letter">u</div>
    <div class="letter">t</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">t</div>
    <div class="letter">h</div>
    <div class="letter">e</div>
    <div class="letter">y</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">l</div>
    <div class="letter">i</div>
    <div class="letter">v</div>
    <div class="letter">e</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">i</div>
    <div class="letter">n</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">o</div>
    <div class="letter">u</div>
    <div class="letter">r</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="letter">h</div>
    <div class="letter">e</div>
    <div class="letter">a</div>
    <div class="letter">r</div>
    <div class="letter">t</div>
    <div class="letter">s</div>
    <div class="letter">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="word">
    <div class="fat">
      <div class="letter">f</div>
      <div class="letter">o</div>
      <div class="letter">r</div>
      <div class="letter">e</div>
      <div class="letter">v</div>
      <div class="letter">e</div>
      <div class="letter">r</div>
      <div class="letter">.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="locations"><a class="buttons" href="/chesterfield/">Chesterfield</a><span>(636) 489-4116</span><a class="buttons" href="/dougherty-ferry/">Dougherty Ferry</a><span>(636) 923-8693</span><a class="buttons" href="/ofallon/">O'Fallon</a><span>(636) 542-4302</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have each letter in it's own div, the display assigned to those divs is inline and has a line-height set to it as well, this is causing the letters to look that way.  If you're to give it a block level display, it should alleviate the issue.
I've removed the display and line-height from your live site and don't really see any changes, on both mobile and desktop views.
If you're wondering how I was able to mimic the device, I used browserstack.com

Here's the snippet in question:

```
body .name .letter {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    /* -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); */
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    line-height: 1em;
    /* -webkit-box-align: center; */
    -ms-flex-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this with me. The opacity is set at 0 to allow the animation to fade in/out, so that is needed. After commenting out everything except for the display properties, the spacing issue is still happening on iOS devices via safari or chrome. :( note: I cannot leave the live site this way, so the comments have been removed from the live site

Comment: Sorry, don't believe I understand your reply.  I wasn't referring to the opacity, I was referring to the display and line-height rules only.  I just copy and pasted the snippet in question since I can't really re-create the exact view on here. It's just a point of reference, not the actual corrected or updated code.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because you had the wrong properties commented out in the snippet you provided in your answer. Removing the display properties and line-height seems to remove the spacing issues on iOS devices, while leaving the look the same on all other devices. Thanks for all the help! Now it seems as is the flex-wrap property isn't working on iOS

Comment: No problem at all.  Sorry about my confusing post but I'm glad that it helped resolve the issue, somewhat. Flex properties are a bit tricky still between different browsers.  I would check out www.caniuse.com for reference.